# ckeditor drag drop widgets

Tags: drag-and-drop, widget, ckeditor

I have latest ckeditor version 4.5.7 with the drag and drop APIs and I have a case where i need to drag and drop a widget from one editor to another.
As this ticket says the suggested functionallity is to fail silently and do nothing.

[link to ckeditor ticket](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13599)

In my case i need to copy the widget if it is dragged to a different editor and to move if it is dragged within the same editor.Second case is already working

Any thoughts on how to do it?

```
editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    var dropTarget = CKEDITOR.plugins.clipboard.getDropTarget( editor );
    editor.editable().attachListener( dropTarget, 'drop', function( evt ) {
    // The target may be some element inside the draggable div (e.g. the image), so get the div.h-card.
    var target = evt.data.getTarget().getAscendant( 'div', true );

    // Initialization of CKEditor data transfer facade is a necessary step to extend and unify native 
    // browser capabilities. For instance, Internet Explorer does not support any other data type than 'text' and 'URL'.
    // Note: evt is an instance of CKEDITOR.dom.event, not a native event.
    CKEDITOR.plugins.clipboard.initDragDataTransfer( evt );

    var dataTransfer = evt.data.dataTransfer;

    // Pass an object with contact details. Based on it, the editor#paste listener in the hcard plugin
    // will create HTML to be inserted into the editor. We could set text/html here as well, but:
    // * It is a more elegant and logical solution that this logic is kept in the hcard plugin.
    // * We do not know now where the content will be dropped and the HTML to be inserted
    // might vary depending on the drop target.
    dataTransfer.setData( 'contact', CONTACTS[ target.data( 'contact' ) ] );

    // We need to set some normal data types to backup values for two reasons:
    // * In some browsers this is necessary to enable drag and drop into text in editor.
    // * The content may be dropped in another place than the editor.
    dataTransfer.setData( 'text/html', target.getText() );
    } );
} );
```

[link to codepen example](http://codepen.io/Duskfall/pen/EKvLYw)

Also if the ckeditor is readonly via the readOnly option i can select some content and drag it to the other editor resulting removing it from the source editor

Answer (score 5):

I found 3 problems here:

1. it is not simple to get contact informations back from the element,
2. as you mentioned CKEditor block widget drag and drop between editors,
3. CKEditor removes drop element from the source area when you do drag and drop.

I managed to solve first two issues.

Ad. 1.

To insert a contact during the cross editor drag and drop the same way the contact is inserted from the contact list, you need to set `contact` data on the data transfer object `dataTransfer.getData( 'contact' );`. Unfortunately, the widget you drag does not store the contact as an object. The simplest way is to store stringified contacts as an additional attribute:

```
<span class="h-card" data-contact=\'' + JSON.stringify( contact ) + '\'>...</span>
```

Ad. 2.

In fact CKEditor block widget drag and drop between editors. To get around you can create a `drop` listener which will be called before the default one (priority 2), and change the drop type from the widget to the contact, so it will be handled the same way as contacts dragged from the list below editors.

```
// Create a drop listener which change the object from the widget to the contact.
editor.on( 'drop', function( evt ) {
  var dataTransfer = evt.data.dataTransfer,
      sourceEditor = dataTransfer.sourceEditor;
      id = dataTransfer.getData( 'cke/widget-id' );

  // If it was a widget from another editor...
  if( sourceEditor && typeof id == "number" ) {
    // ...get contact info from the data attribute...
    var contact = sourceEditor.widgets.instances[ id ].element.data( 'contact' );
    contact = JSON.parse( contact );

    // ...set the contact info...
    dataTransfer.setData( 'contact', contact );

    // ...and remove the information that it was a widget.
    dataTransfer.setData( 'cke/widget-id', null );            
  }
}, null, null, 2 );
```

Ad. 3.

I was not able to prevent CKEditor form removing dragged element without preventing drop. Removal is done by this code: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/06362a8715809f23d439986a122b87a37eef2e13/plugins/clipboard/plugin.js#L1409 and is not prepared to be prevented. My another idea was to prevent this drag and drop and fire separate drop event, but unfortunately then I do not have a drop position. You can change the clipboard plugin to prevent removing source element and add something like:

```
if( dataTransfer.getData( 'doNotRemoveSource' )
  dataTransfer.sourceEditor.editable().extractHtmlFromRange( dragRange );
```

But I do not promise it will work properly, it may need some more changes in the widget system which also listen on the drop event.

The whole solution is a hack, perfect solution needs deeper changes in the clipboard plugin.

You can find my solution here: http://codepen.io/pjasiun/pen/aNLWWM

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do it like you said by prioritizing the events

Firstly in the new widget plugin i used the dragstart event

```
editor.on("dragstart", function (evt) {
     evt.stop();
     var target = evt.data.target;

     if (isDomDragHandler(target)) {
         var widget = evt.editor.widgets.getByElement(target);
         CKEDITOR.plugins.clipboard.initDragDataTransfer(evt, evt.editor);
         evt.data.dataTransfer.setData('cke/widget-id', widget.id);
         evt.data.dataTransfer.setData('cke/editor-name', evt.editor.name);
         evt.data.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', widget.element.getOuterHtml());

         // IE needs focus.
         editor.focus();

         // and widget need to be focused on drag start (#12172#comment:10).
         widget.focus();
     }
}, null, null, 1);
```

Then I use a drop event with priority 2 ( 1 is the default one which is called before this one).

I use the validation to check if the widget is dragged inside the editor. If it is then i don't want to create a new widget, but move the existing one so we cancel this event

```
editor.on('drop', function (evt) {
    // do nothing if widget is dragged in source segment
    if (evt.editor.name.indexOf("sourceSegment") != -1) {
       evt.cancel();
       return;
    }

    //get hold of global data transfer object
    var dataTransfer = evt.data.dataTransfer;
    var sourceEditorName = dataTransfer.getData('cke/editor-name');

    if (sourceEditorName == evt.editor.name) return;
}, null, null, 2);      // 2rd called
```

Finally we must use another listener, again drop effect to tell if the event comes from the same editor or from another editor, to set the data.

```
editor.on('drop', function (evt) {

    var dataTransfer = evt.data.dataTransfer,
        id = dataTransfer.getData('cke/widget-id'),
        transferType = dataTransfer.getTransferType(editor);

        // Disable cross-editor drag & drop for widgets - #13599.
    if (id !== '' && transferType === CKEDITOR.DATA_TRANSFER_CROSS_EDITORS) {
       //do nothing
    }

    if (id === '' || transferType == CKEDITOR.DATA_TRANSFER_INTERNAL) {
       return;
    }

    evt.data.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', evt.data.dataTransfer.getData('text/html'));
}, null, null, 9999);      // 3rd called
```

Final change was to comment out the cancelation of the event in widget plugin

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/widget/plugin.js#L2381

```
// Disable cross-editor drag & drop for widgets - #13599.
if ( id !== '' && transferType === CKEDITOR.DATA_TRANSFER_CROSS_EDITORS ) {
    //evt.cancel(); <---- I commented this one
    return;
}
```

This way you can drag, widgets between editors to copy from source to target editor, and move widgets inside the same editor.

Disclaimer: 
This solution i came up is the best i found without manipulating the core functionallity of the ckeditor itself too much (only 1 line). However if someone has a better solution please comment!